# Confusion with Exchange 2013 Setup - Multiple Domains

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange, exchange-2013

I have a new install of Exchange 2013, and have added 4 authoritative domains, now I am adding mail boxes.  If I want to have an info@ email address on each, how can I accomplish this?  It seems like the first works fine, then when I add the second it appends a number to the user name like info2@ and so on.  is that just for the domain controller so it does not have dupe user name? Or have I configured something wrong?
I am a bit lost and would love any kind of guidance.

Comment: Do you want to have a separate `info` mailbox for each domain, or for all 4 addresses to go to the same mailbox?

Comment: different mailboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Exchange mailbox is tied to an Active Directory user account, and user accounts have to be globally unique; you'll need a different account for each mailbox, like:

- InfoDomA -> info@domainA.com
- InfoDomB -> info@domainB.com
- InfoDomC -> info@domainC.com

I suggest you first create the user accounts in Active Directory, and then create the Exchange mailboxes by linking them to the already-existing users.

Comment: If I add them as new accounts, will I be able to use info@ for each, or will it only work if I setup the accounts first?

Comment: You'll be able to use info@ email accounts for each domain.  No problem there.  Just that the user account has to be unique (within the AD domain).  EDIT: you'll also most likely have to uncheck the auto apply email policy and then add your "info@" and remove the old "info2@"

Comment: I will go ahead and try this and let you know how it goes

Comment: I ended up setting up organization units for each site, this is working good.